# Converting from UIImage to a SwiftUI Image results in a blank image of the same size

Tags: uikit, swiftui

I am trying to convert a [UIImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage) to a SwiftUI [Image](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image) using the [init(uiImage:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image/3269665-init) initializer. My UIImage itself is created from a CIImage generated by a CIQRCodeGenerator CIFilter. I am running my code on a Playground in Xcode 11.1 GM seed 1. Here is the entirety of my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

func qrCodeImage(for string: String) -> Image? {
  let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
  guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }
  qrFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

  guard let ciImage = qrFilter.outputImage else { return nil }
  let uiImage = UIImage(ciImage: ciImage)
  let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)

  return image
}

let image = qrCodeImage(for: "fdsa")
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Even when I transform the image with `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)`, the resulting SwiftUI Image at the end is still the same size, but blank.

Comment: Does any of this help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297704/convert-uiimage-to-nsdata-and-convert-back-to-uiimage-in-swift

Comment: I don't think it helps. That question is from 2015. SwiftUI was unveiled in 2019. My question is about converting a UIImage to a SwiftUI Image.

Comment: Encounter same problem, but resolved it using solution from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239980/generating-qr-code-with-swiftui-shows-empty-picture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating QR Code with SwiftUI shows empty picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239980/generating-qr-code-with-swiftui-shows-empty-picture)

Answer (score 15):

Following solution provided in: [Generating QR Code with SwiftUI shows empty picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239980/generating-qr-code-with-swiftui-shows-empty-picture)

Here is the code:

```
var ciContext = CIContext()

func qrCodeImage(for string: String) -> Image? {
    let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    guard let qrFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") else { return nil }
    qrFilter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")

    guard let ciImage = qrFilter.outputImage else { return nil }
    let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: ciImage.extent)

    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)

    let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)

    return image
}

 let image = qrCodeImage(for: "fdsa")
```

Result:

[screenshot in swift playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nffi9.png)

Answer (score 5):

Can confirm I encounter the same issue with a SwiftUI `Image` using a `UIImage` initialized from data. Can verify that the image is loaded when paused in debugging, but it does not display in the SwiftUI Image.

This solution worked for me: explicitly specify the image rendering mode. In my case I added the following: `.renderingMode(.original)`

Comment: Have you tried this on my playground example? I changed `let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage)` to `let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage).renderingMode(.original)` but I got the same result.

Comment: No, I did not. Here is the full declaration I use. Only adding the renderingMode worked in my case, but maybe there is also a dependency on the other values: `Image(uiImage: photo.thumbnailImage!).renderingMode(.original).resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).frame(width: 50, height: 50).cornerRadius(25)`

Answer (score 1):

@Eugene remark worked for me:

```
let image = Image(uiImage: uiImage).renderingMode(.original)
```