# "Communications error" - AVFoundation Camera

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, camera, avfoundation

So i'm using AVFoundation to make a camera, but for some reason i keep getting this error when i go to capture, most of the time it results in my phone losing connection to Xcode and crashing the app, I also use it to crop images and get the same sort of error.
Is anybody able to tell me why this error occurs?

```
Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x19b14ca80> {  count = 1, 
contents = "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x19b14ce78> { 
length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" } }>
```

Here is the code for the capture:

```
public func capturePictureWithCompletition(imageCompletition: (UIImage?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        var blockHandler = { (imageDataSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if let imageDataSampleBuffer = imageDataSampleBuffer {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                imageCompletition(image?.normalizedImages, nil)
            } else {
                imageCompletition(nil, error)
            }
        }

        if self.cameraIsSetup {
            if self.cameraOutputMode == .StillImage {
                if let stillImageOutput = self.stillImageOutput {
                    let connection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
                    stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connection, completionHandler: blockHandler)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a memory crashing problem.
Try to resize your image.

This question can help you: [How to Resize image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314412/how-to-resize-image-in-swift)