# Swift 4: Pinch gesture, image size bounce back

Tags: ios, swift, image, gesture

I would like to use a pinch gesture to change the size of the image. With the code shown below I achieve that, but every time I pinch the picture after that, the image bounces back to the original size.

```
@IBAction func pinchGestureActivated(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
}
```

Comment: Is this the only code that transform the imageView in your project?

Comment: using `imageView.transform` only changes the scale or size of the imageView UI component, not the image itself. The imageView is just an image container. Take a look at other answers already on here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Resize image in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314412/how-to-resize-image-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening:

- Your `imageView` is 100 x 100.
- You pinch it, it goes down to 20 x 20.
- Pinch ends. // Your imageView size hasn't changed. It has just been transformed. None of the changes reflect on it.
- You pinch again. // The imageView is still 100 x 100. So the transformation takes place again from 100 x 100.

When the `transform` property of any UIView subclass is **not** set to the `identity`, the frame won't actually be changed, and that is probably the reason you're observing this. We can work with that:

```
@IBAction func pinchGestureActivated(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    imageView.transform = imageView.transform.scaledBy(x: sender.scale, y: sender.scale)
}
```

This should do the job :)

Comment: and where is bounce animation?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov the question was not about a bounce animation, but about the image not staying the same size on further interaction after it had been resized. This answer resolves that issue.