# Customizing image size in code in iOS navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uinavigationbar

This is the code I'm using to set an image in the title of the nativation bar,

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

let image = UIImage(named: "fullLogo")
imageView.image = image

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

The issue is that image appears a little too big. How do I resize the image in code? I tried many combinations of the width and height but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/1624935-titleview):

> Custom title views are centered on the navigation bar and may be resized to fit.

That's what happening with your image view. The solution can be to add `imageView` as subview to `UIView` and assign `UIView` to `titleView` property.

The easier solution may be to set `imageView.contentMode` to `.center` but in this case you need to be sure that your `fullLogo` image is actually 100x30, if it is bigger than `titleView` frame calculated by iOS your image will overlay navigation bar and view controller's view.

And you can init your `UIImageView` or container `UIView` with `frame: .zero` because it's frame will be recalculated in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

For resizing the image this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31314494/5807290) would help. Hope this helps.

Happy Coding.