# How to resize an image that is being printed?

Tags: swift, uiimage, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I am trying to print A QR Code that has been generated by Swift when I print it out it is taking up the whole sheet I am wanting to resize the image and make it smaller. Aprox 200px x 200px

I have tried using different UIImage resize functions and is still coming out the same. I have also tried to resize the image with the printController

```
func printImage(img:UIImage) {
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.jobName = "Printing \(myTextField.text) 's QR code"
    printInfo.outputType = .photoGrayscale
    self.resizeImage(img, targetSize: CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0))

    printController.printInfo = printInfo



    printController.printingItem = img

    printController.present(animated: true) { (_, isPrinted, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if isPrinted {
                print("QR Code Has Been Printed :)")
            } else {
                print("QR Code Not Printed")
            }

        }
    }
} 

func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
let size = image.size

let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height

// Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
var newSize: CGSize
if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
    newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * heightRatio, size.height * heightRatio)
} else {
    newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * widthRatio,  size.height * widthRatio)
}

// This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

// Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
image.drawInRect(rect)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return newImage
}
```

I am expecting a small QR Code Aprox 200px by 200px. I am currently getting a A4 Size QR Code

Comment: Which code you have tried to resize `img`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314412/how-to-resize-image-in-swift

Comment: Please update your code with your try.

Comment: I have updated now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As method `resizeImage` is returning new `UIImage` you need store result of

```
self.resizeImage(img, targetSize: CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0))
```

in another object like:

```
let resizedImage = self.resizeImage(img, targetSize: CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0))
```

And now you can use this `resizedImage` image for print like:

```
printController.printingItem = resizedImage
```

Hope this will help.

**EDIT:**

Below is update code:

```
func printImage(img:UIImage) {

    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared

    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.jobName = "Printing 's QR code"
    printInfo.outputType = .photoGrayscale

    if let resizedImage = self.resizeImage(image: img, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)) {

        printController.printInfo = printInfo
        printController.printingItem = resizedImage

        printController.present(animated: true) { (_, isPrinted, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if isPrinted {
                    print("QR Code Has Been Printed :)")
                } else {
                    print("QR Code Not Printed")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

    let size = image.size
    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Comment: I Have now done that but i am getting error:  Argument labels '(_:, _:)' do not match any available overloads.  This is appearing on the line: let resized image

Comment: Happy to help you. :)

Comment: Sorry I have just re ran the code and the image has decressed in size but is now blury which can not be read by a qr scanner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186115/discussion-between-luke-and-dharmesh-kheni).